# Powershell set a variable and print but nothing

Tags: powershell

```
SET ML_PATH=E:\Workspace\Handson-ml2
echo $ML_PATH
```

printed nothing.

```
echo "ML_PATH = $ML_PATH"
```

printed just:
ML_PATH =

How could i set a variable in powershell and print the variable like echo of linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a variable in PowerShell using the `$varname =` syntax:

```
$ML_PATH = "E:\Workspace\Handson-ml2"
Write-Output $ML_PATH
```

Note: `echo` is an *alias*  for the `Write-Output` cmdlet which you can determine using the `Get-Alias` cmdlet:

```
Get-Alias echo

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```